# How can I fix the numerical misbehavior of a function in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am experiencing some numerical misbehavior, probably because I've made some error writing the scripts (I am a newbie).

I wrote a code that makes a prefab "growing" following some mathematical rules. These rules are Ordinary Differential Equations solved by Runge-Kutta numerical method (https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/arithmetic/article.php/c4597/Numerical-Computing-in-C.htm)

The growth script has a variable calculated as ODE solution each timestep:

```
public void UpdateGrowth()
{

    if (timeManager.IsDayElapsed && timeManager.Seconds <= setup.SimulationTime)
    {
        if (internodeID <= setup.StaticGeneticInfo.MaxInternodeNumber)
            setup.Manager.InternodesCurrentLenght[internodeID - 1] = transform.localScale.y;

        float nextValue = nextStepValue.NextStepValue;
        float dayCount = timeManager.Days;
        annualLengthGrowth = Runge.runge(0.0f, 1.0f, nextValue, .1f, new Runge.Function(Equation.equation));
       
        annualGrowth = new Vector3(annualWidthGrowth, annualLengthGrowth, annualWidthGrowth);

        nextStepValue.NextStepValue = annualLengthGrowth;

        currentLenght = (annualGrowth.y);
```

The classRunge is the one for Runge-Kutta numerical method:

```
    public class Runge
{
    //declare a delegate that takes a float and returns
    public delegate float Function(float dayCount, float annualGrowth);
    public static float runge(float a, float b, float value, float step, Function f)
    {
        float dayCount,  w, k1, k2, k3, k4;
        dayCount = a;
        w = value;
        for (int i = 0; i < (b - a) / step; i++)
        {
            k1 = step * f(dayCount, w);
            k2 = step * f(dayCount + step / 2f, w + k1 / 2f);
            k3 = step * f(dayCount + step / 2f, w + k2 / 2f);
            k4 = step * f(dayCount + step, w + k3);
            w = w + (k1 + 2f * k2 + 2f * k3 + k4) / 6f;
            dayCount = a + i * step;
        }
        return w;
    }
}
```

The equation to solve is in equation script:

```
public void Update()
{
    dayCount = time.Days;
}

public static float equation(float dayCount, float annualGrowth)
{
    float y_prime;

    float maxLenght = (1 - (setup.Manager.TotalLenght() / maxTreeHeight));
    temp = (float)-Math.Pow(((180 - dayCount) / 180), 2) * a + a;
    alfaT = temp / a;
    y_prime = alfaT * annualGrowth * (1 - (annualGrowth / maxLenght));

    return y_prime;      
}
```

While the daycount is given by timemanager script:

```
private void Start()
{
    isdayElapsed = false;
}

private void Update()
{
    rate += Time.deltaTime;

    if (rate > 1)
    {
        rate = 0;
        seconds++;
        days++;
        isdayElapsed = true;
    }

    if (days > 365)
    {
        days = 0;
    }
}
```

The issue I am experiencing is that in the equation script, the dayCount variable is passed from 0 to 1, then from 1 is "resetting" calculating back from 0. This made annualLenghtGrowth in growth script miscalculated. Of course it should continue with 2, 3 ,4 and so on until 365.
It looks like is resetting each update while the dayCount is working fine.
I can't figure out where and what is the problem, please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: dayCount = time.Days;
Time.Days is updating?

Comment: yes, It works fine counting the days (as seconds). The Days are taken from timemanager script